# Input con salto de linea al dato que escribe el usuario

Tags: python

quisiera que al tomar el dato al usuario, lo que escriba el usuario, se vaya mostrando en la siguiente linea:

**Ejemplo que se muestre así:**

Escribe tu nombre:

Manuel

**Y no se muestre así:**

Escribe tu nombre: Manuel

```
nombre = input("Escribe tu nombre:")
edad = int(input("Escribe tu edad:"))
print("Te llamas",nombre,"y tienes",edad,"años.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te refieres a que el input tome el dato del usuario desde la línea inferior esto podría ayudarte:

```
nombre = input("Escribe tu nombre:\n")
edad = int(input("Escribe tu edad:\n"))
print("Te llamas",nombre,"y tienes",edad,"años.")
```

El output seria este:

```
>>Escribe tu nombre:
Manuel
>>Escribe tu edad:
15
>>Te llamas Manuel y tienes 15 años.
```

Answer (score 2):

Agrega un `\n` donde desee una nueva línea:

```
nombre = input("Escribe tu nombre:\n")
edad = int(input("Escribe tu edad:\n"))
print("Te llamas",nombre,"y tienes",edad,"años.")
```

produce:

```
Escribe tu nombre:
Manual
Escribe tu edad:
15
Te llamas Manual y tienes 15 años.

Process finished with exit code 0
```